# Could a method in the service class (layer) call another method in the same service?

Tags: java, service, soa

Seeking advice on if this violates the Service layer design principles in SOA. My design is simple- `Endpoint -> Service -> Repository`. The Service layer returns a DTO to the endpoint which is translated into the response object.

Currently my Endpoint and Service layer contracts are the following

Endpoint

```
public interface Order {

     OrderInfoResponse getOrderInfo(String orderId);

     OrderStatusResponse isOrderComplete(String orderId);
}
```

Service

```
public interface OrderService {

    OrderDTO getOrder(String orderId);

    boolean getOrderStatus(String orderId);
}
```

Now in my implementation, the `getOrderStatus` Service method calls the `getOrder` method to query the order and then returns a boolean field of the retrieved Order entity.

My Reasoning so far:

1. Why do I have an endpoint to just retrieve a status?

   - I have a requirement for my application to expose just the status of the order. I figured, having the endpoint return a "lightweight" object- `OrderStatusResponse`, which essentially just contains a boolean flag, would be a simpler API, lighter payload over the wire, easier for the consumer to understand and parse, etc.
2. A separate Service method would decouple my endpoint from the existing `getOrderInfo` service method and it's intended operation. The dedicated service method would allow greater flexibility if more requirements were to come in
3. Countering the above point, couldn't my endpoint use the existing `getOrderInfo` service method, retrieve the full Order DTO and pull out the necessary boolean field and build the response? In that case, no new service method at all.

Question:

1. [MAIN Q] Is it acceptable to have one service method call another in the same
   service class?
2. If not, what would be the right way to do this?
3. Are there flaws in my reasoning?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem calling your own API from within your service - if it is open to the "public" it is open for your internal use. The point is within your service, knowing internal service structure, you can take shortcuts. For instance, in your case, why retrieve a full order when you just need the order status

Comment: Thanks! I came around to thinking the same thing- why retrieve a full order when I just need the status. I ended up defining a new repo method for only Order status and not calling another service method. But, thank you for the insight on how calling another service method is also do-able. Do you think doing so might be pointing to a hidden problem? Like for instance here I should have just retrieved on status instead of the Order object.

Comment: I think It depends on too many variables to say. I think the best guideline I can say here is not to use it as a default - as I said in the reply APIs are built for external users and hide internal structures, this is something you don't need to do for internal behavior